# How to reverse engineer docker-compose up?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We have an existing deployment using docker-compose in a production system, but we no longer know who deploy and what is the docker-compose file that is being used during the deployment. ;)

Is there a way to reverse engineer existing docker-compose deployment so we can get the original file?

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly confident there is not possible (although I hope I am wrong as it'd be a useful process).

I do have a few tips on how you could possibly identify your docker-compose config:

- Check the running containers noting the container name. Docker-compose would name them `[folder_name]-[service_name]_[number]`. You could likely use the find command to search for the `[folder_name]`.

```
docker ps -a
# Identify service
find / -type d -name "[folder_name]"
```

- Inspect the container. Note things such as Mounts (for volume mounts), and Configs (for environment variables, images, etc.).

```
docker inspect [container_id]
```